# Why isnt this SQL command working

Tags: sql

```
SELECT info, date
FROM Professor, Professor_Comment, Comment
WHERE pID = ?
AND Professor_Comment.pcID = Professor.pcID
AND Comment.commID = Professor_Comment.commID;
;
```

[image: sql of 3 tables]

Comment: Not sure this matters but you have two `;` at the end - also you have `pID = ?` but pID is ambiguous because it appears in `Professor` and `Professor_Comment`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That's likely to be because the `pID` is ambigious and the `Professor` doesn't have a `pcID`.

Try this:

```
SELECT info, date
FROM Professor_Comment, Comment
WHERE pID = ?
AND Comment.commID = Professor_Comment.commID;
```

However, I prefer the explicit JOIN syntax:

```
SELECT info, date
FROM Professor_Comment
JOIN Comment ON Comment.commID = Professor_Comment.commID
WHERE pID = ?;
```

Comment: As added the Professor table DOES have a pcID in it. 'The pID = ?' is used because its pulling that information based on that PK of 'pID'

Comment: pcID is just a surrogate key allowing data to travel from Professor -> -> Professor_Comment -> Comment

Answer (score 0):

1. You have `pID = ?`, but pID is ambiguous because it appears in `Professor` and `Professor_Comment`

   Change that sole pID to either `Professor.pID` or `Professor_Comment.pID`
2. You have `Professor_Comment.pcID = Professor.pcID`, the Professor table has it listed as `dID`, not pcID